# converting a 'melted' multicolumn index data frame to a heirarchial list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a 'melted' data frame, df, for which there are multiple indexing columns and a single observation column.

This is a 'dense' data frame. I.e. there is an observation present for every combination of values in the indexing columns. Also, it is one-to-one. I.e. each combination of index values corresponds to a single observed value.

I am trying to write an automatic way to convert this into a heirarchial list structure, hl, such that the names of the nth level of the list correspond to the unique values from the nth column of the data frame and the entries of the list are then the corresponding values from the observation column of the data frame.

E.g. the names of hl at level 'n' could be given by

```
df[[colnames(df)[n]]]%>%unique()
```

The goal then is to get the example below to work without having to explicitly construct a for loop for every individual column.
Not needing to construct the loops manually is important because I will not know, apriori, how many indexing columns will be present in the data frame.
An example

```
require(dplyr)
tempA=rep(letters[1:3],9)
tempB=c(rep(mapply(function(x){rep(LETTERS[x],3)},c(1:3)),3))
tempC=c(mapply(function(x){rep(x,9)},c(1:3)))
tempObs=paste(tempA,tempB,tempC,sep="_")
df=data.frame(A=tempA,B=tempB,C=tempC,Obs=tempObs)
df

hl=list()
for(iA in df$A%>%unique){
    hl[[iA]]=list()
    for(iB in df$B%>%unique){
        hl[[iA]][[iB]]=list()
        for(iC in df$C%>%unique){
            hl[[iA]][[iB]][[iC]]=(df%>%
                filter(A==iA,B==iB,C==iC))$Obs[1]
        }
    }
}

hl
hl[['a']][['A']][[1]]
```

Yields:

```
A   B   C   Obs
a   A   1   a_A_1
b   A   1   b_A_1
c   A   1   c_A_1
a   B   1   a_B_1
b   B   1   b_B_1
c   B   1   c_B_1
a   C   1   a_C_1
b   C   1   b_C_1
c   C   1   c_C_1
a   A   2   a_A_2
b   A   2   b_A_2
c   A   2   c_A_2
a   B   2   a_B_2
b   B   2   b_B_2
c   B   2   c_B_2
a   C   2   a_C_2
b   C   2   b_C_2
c   C   2   c_C_2
a   A   3   a_A_3
b   A   3   b_A_3
c   A   3   c_A_3
a   B   3   a_B_3
b   B   3   b_B_3
c   B   3   c_B_3
a   C   3   a_C_3
b   C   3   b_C_3
c   C   3   c_C_3

$a

    $A

            a_A_1
            a_A_2
            a_A_3

    $B

            a_B_1
            a_B_2
            a_B_3

    $C

            a_C_1
            a_C_2
            a_C_3

$b

    $A

            b_A_1
            b_A_2
            b_A_3

    $B

            b_B_1
            b_B_2
            b_B_3

    $C

            b_C_1
            b_C_2
            b_C_3

$c

    $A

            c_A_1
            c_A_2
            c_A_3

    $B

            c_B_1
            c_B_2
            c_B_3

    $C

            c_C_1
            c_C_2
            c_C_3

a_A_1
```

After some headscratching, I can get a naive solution using recursion. However, this seems highly inelegant to me...

```
df_to_hl <- function(df,
                     indCols=(df%>%colnames)[c(1:(length(df%>%colnames)-1))],
                     iCol=1,vList=c()){
    hl=list()
    if(iCol<length(indCols)){
        for(iVal in df[[indCols[iCol]]]%>%unique){
            hl[[iVal]]=df_to_hl(df,indCols,iCol+1,vList=c(vList,iVal))
        }
    } else {
        for(iVal in df[[indCols[iCol]]]%>%unique){
            hl[[iVal]]=(df%>%filter_(paste(indCols,'==',shQuote(c(vList,iVal)),collapse="&")))[[last(df%>%colnames)]][1]
        }
    }
    return(hl)
}
```

Comment: If this can be for an unknown number of columns, at what point will you know how many there are? Will you have a vector of index names to work with or something else?

Comment: As stated in the post, the number of index columns will be one less than the total number of columns in the data frame, so once df is given, the number of columns could be found by (df%>%colnames%>%length)-1. Similarly, the names of the index columns would be given by (df%>%colnames)[length(df%>%colnames)-1]... naievely, I think recursion should yield a solution to this, but that tends to run very slowly (at least in R ... Rcpp may yield reasonable speed, particluarly if recursion is refactored using stack structures)